# Insert missing data ranges in table with list of multiple parameters

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
Date_from <- c("2013-01-01","2013-02-02","2013-05-10","2013-09-13","2013-12-02","2013-01-01","2013-02-02","2013-05-10","2013-09-13","2013-12-02","2013-01-01","2013-02-02","2013-05-10","2013-09-13","2013-12-02")
Date_to <- c("2013-02-01","2013-05-07","2013-08-12","2013-11-18","2013-12-31","2013-02-01","2013-05-07","2013-08-12","2013-11-18","2013-12-31","2013-02-01","2013-05-07","2013-08-12","2013-11-18","2013-12-31")
y <- data.frame(Date_from,Date_to)
y$concentration <- c("1.4","1.5","2.5","1.5","3.5","1.4","1.5","2.5","1.5","3.5","1.4","1.5","2.5","1.5","3.5")
y$Parameter<-c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C")
y$Date_from <- as.Date(y$Date_from)
y$Date_to <- as.Date(y$Date_to)
y$concentration <- as.numeric(y$concentration)
```

I will need to go through the data frame and detect missing date ranges for each of the parameters and then insert those missing date ranges including an `NA` for `concentration` and the respective parameter name.

UPDATE:

The following code added the missing date ranges but I couldn´t figure out how to add the paraemter name for each missing date range:

```
adding<-data.frame(Parameter=NA,concentration=NA,Date_from=y$Date_to[-nrow(y)]+1, Date_to=y$Date_from[-1]-1)
adding<-adding[ adding$Date_from<=adding$Date_to,]
res<-rbind(y,adding)
y <- res[order(res$Date_from),]
```

The result should look like this:

```
Date_from    Date_to concentration Parameter
2013-01-01 2013-02-01           1.4         A
2013-02-02 2013-05-07           1.5         A
2013-05-08 2013-05-09            NA         A
2013-05-10 2013-08-12           2.5         A
2018-08-13 2013-09-12            NA         A
2013-09-13 2013-11-18           1.5         A
2013-11-19 2013-12-01            NA         A
2013-12-02 2013-12-31           3.5         A
2013-01-01 2013-02-01           1.4         B
2013-02-02 2013-05-07           1.5         B  
2013-05-08 2013-05-09            NA         B
2013-05-10 2013-08-12           2.5         B
2018-08-13 2013-09-12            NA         B 
2013-09-13 2013-11-18           1.5         B
2013-11-19 2013-12-01            NA         B
2013-12-02 2013-12-31           3.5         B
2013-01-01 2013-02-01           1.4         C
2013-02-02 2013-05-07           1.5         C
2013-05-08 2013-05-09            NA         C
2013-05-10 2013-08-12           2.5         C
2018-08-13 2013-09-12            NA         C
2013-09-13 2013-11-18           1.5         C
2013-11-19 2013-12-01            NA         C
2013-12-02 2013-12-31           3.5         C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Is this what you need? 

Date_from <- c("2013-01-01","2013-02-02","2013-05-10","2013-09-13","2013-12-02","2013-01-01","2013-02-02","2013-05-10","2013-09-13","2013-12-02","2013-01-01","2013-02-02","2013-05-10","2013-09-13","2013-12-02")
Date_to <- c("2013-02-01","2013-05-07","2013-08-12","2013-11-18","2013-12-31","2013-02-01","2013-05-07","2013-08-12","2013-11-18","2013-12-31","2013-02-01","2013-05-07","2013-08-12","2013-11-18","2013-12-31")
y <- data.frame(Date_from,Date_to)
y$concentration <- c("1.4","1.5","2.5","1.5","3.5","1.4","1.5","2.5","1.5","3.5","1.4","1.5","2.5","1.5","3.5")
y$Parameter<-c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C")
y$Date_from <- as.Date(y$Date_from)
y$Date_to <- as.Date(y$Date_to)
y$concentration <- as.numeric(y$concentration)

adding<-data.frame(Parameter=NA, concentration=NA, Date_from=y$Date_to[-nrow(y)]+1, Date_to=y$Date_from[-1]-1)
adding<-adding[ adding$Date_from<=adding$Date_to,]
adding$Parameter <- rep(c("A","B","C"),3)
res<-rbind(y,adding)

y <- res[order(res$Date_from),]
```

Comment: This should give you the format you desire. Not the prettiest way of doing though.

Comment: The line `adding$Parameter <- rep(c("A","B","C"),3)` adds the Parameters names to the wrong date ranges, e.g. it adds `A` to the range `2013-05-08 to 2013-05-09`, only. I would need to let R copy each parameter name to the new row as I have more than those three example parameter names.

Comment: `adding<-data.frame(Parameter=y$Parameter[-nrow(y)], 
                   concentration=NA, 
                   Date_from=y$Date_to[-nrow(y)]+1,
                   Date_to=y$Date_from[-1]-1)`
Would this be ok?
In which case you can remove the line: 
`adding$Parameter <- rep(c("A","B","C"),3)`